# unity vuforia extended tracked problems

Tags: unity-game-engine, vuforia

i need help. I use unity2018.2.12f1&Vuforia 7.5.26. My task - dont hide object, after image doesnt in FOV. I made track device pose, positional mode, optimize for images and deleted code OnTrackingLost(). It works incorect. When status is NOT_FOUND camera does not see the model but model did not dissappaer. You can watch that in video https://youtu.be/FHGHULr8J90

```
 public void OnTrackableStateChanged(
    TrackableBehaviour.Status previousStatus,
    TrackableBehaviour.Status newStatus)
{
    m_PreviousStatus = previousStatus;
    m_NewStatus = newStatus;

    if (newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.DETECTED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED ||
        newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.EXTENDED_TRACKED)
    {
        Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");
        OnTrackingFound();
    }
    //else if (previousStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.TRACKED &&
    //         newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE)
    //{
    //    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " lost");
    //    OnTrackingLost();
    //}
    //else
    //{
    //    // For combo of previousStatus=UNKNOWN + newStatus=UNKNOWN|NOT_FOUND
    //    // Vuforia is starting, but tracking has not been lost or found yet
    //    // Call OnTrackingLost() to hide the augmentations
    //    OnTrackingLost();
    //}
}
```

Comment: Please show some code.

Comment: Well that works this way because of extended tracking. It keeps tracking the marker even if it is not in the field of view.

Comment: add code, but i think problem ist in code

Comment: @AliKanat it is doesnt work as need. When image lost camera doesnt watch on my object

Comment: Sorry i do not really understand what you are saying. Try not using extended tracking. The whole point of extended tracking is to track markers when they are not visible to your camera.

Comment: @AliKanat i need make this -> when my camera found marker i create object. How to make it so that after the image target is not in FOV, the model does not disappear?

Answer (score 0):

Okay now i understood what you meant. Normally you do not have to change anything in your script if you are using Extended Tracking. `newStatus == TrackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE` this statement will always be true if your camera does not lost tracking(not tracking of marker, tracking in general). This can only happen if environment does not have enough features or e.g. you are looking towards a white wall. **Otherwise** as long as you use ´Extended Tracking` it will keep tracking that marker.

The problem in your case could be application is expecting a marker at that position because it is still tracking the marker but there is no marker because you switch to some other tab. Normally extended tracking works when you track the marker and look away and it is still tracked. You should check the `newStatus`and see what happens when you switch tab.

Comment: whean i switch tab newStatus == rackableBehaviour.Status.NO_POSE and camera dont move and dont see my object

Comment: Well as i said vuforia saves the features at that position when you switch tabs i can not track device anymore.